# Pointer-Event callbacks not triggered in jQuery & Dojo app

Tags: jquery, dojo

When I create a jQuery-Dialog and fill it with a complex Dojo application (not iframe), this is not working anymore :

```
dojo.connect(this.wTree, "onClick", function (item) {
  thiz.onModeChanged(types.FILE_PANEL_LAYOUT.TREE);
});
```

and this also does not :

```
this.wThumb.domNode.onclick=function(){
  thiz.onModeChanged(types.FILE_PANEL_LAYOUT.THUMB);
};
```

Update : Not only pointer events are broken but also the Dijit focus system is screwed. For instance all keyboard events like Escape on Dijit-Dialogs are not working  any more as well the classic dojo.onKey events are gone.

An idea how I can get my pointer events back? When create the modal dialog with something else like MooTools-Squeeze-Box its all working (jQuery not loaded).

Is there a tweak to tell jQuery not to touch my pointer events?

Comment: I think it will be pretty hard to tell you what the problem is only by this code. You're only giving us the code that isn't executing, but in orde to know why it isn't executing we need more than that. Can you give us a more complete example of what you're trying to achieve (and optionally create a fiddle of it?).